# PHP: The Reflection API - Great Addition To PHP With Little Use

Tags: php, oop, documentation

Reflection API is great thing out there to manipulate the OOP stuff and looks like most of the developers aren't even aware of that or have never used that.

**Reflection API Claims:**

> PHP 5 comes with a complete reflection
>   API that adds the ability to
>   reverse-engineer classes, interfaces,
>   functions, methods and extensions.
>   Additionally, the reflection API
>   offers ways to retrieve doc comments
>   for functions, classes and methods.

**Question:**

- Why it has almost no documentation for most of its methods/properties? You see this message there on the documentation:

> This function is currently not
>   documented; only its argument list is
>   available.

Where to find its documentation at all?

- Is it future-compatible, in other words, can i use in my MVC framework?
- Why it is used less often, anything wrong with it?

Comment: @sarfraz I've heard a lot of criticism aimed at it's performance. Not exactly sure how well founded they are but apparently it's slow. -- Also there aren't many good examples around of it being put to good use past document generation. I don't think people generally know what's possible with it. -- I'm curious to see any real world examples where it's being used _outside the box_ so to speak. Would be great if you added that to your question.

Comment: @anomareh: thanks for your comment and performance point. The one scenorio i know of is that when you use `call_user_func_array` with referenced arguments, it will throw an error, but there are ways to deal with that using reflection api. Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Reflection is definitely here to stay. You may use it, but keep in mind it is said to be slow and overkill for simple UseCases. Using one of the functions in the [Classes/Objects function package](http://de.php.net/manual/en/ref.classobj.php) is often the faster alternative.

A UseCase where Reflection comes in handy is when parsing for annotations in the DocBlock of a class. For instance, PHPUnit uses the annotations @test to tell the PHPUnit TestRunner that it should consider a method a test. The @covers annotation will help it collect Code Coverage data. The FLOW3 framework makes use of [Annotations for their AOP framework](http://docs.typo3.org/flow/TYPO3FlowDocumentation/TheDefinitiveGuide/PartIII/AspectOrientedProgramming.html).

Unfortunately, some of the newer additions to PHP > 5.3, are not documented yet that much. [Just look at the SPL](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php). Same thing. That doesn't mean you cannot use it though. The Reflection API is very expressive and easy to figure out from the method names. And Google often has blog posts about how to use certain extensions. For the Reflection API, check out:

- http://www.phpriot.com/articles/reflection-api
- http://mark-story.com/posts/view/using-the-php-reflection-api-for-fun-and-profit
- http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/16/4/0
- http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/125-PHP-5s-Reflection-API.html

and for SPL

- http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-SPL.html

---

Something cool I just discovered recently. As of 5.1.2, you can [invoke the Reflection API from the command line](http://de.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php) too:

```
$php --rf strtotime
Function [ <internal:date> function strtotime ] {

  - Parameters [2] {
    Parameter #0 [ <required> $time ]
    Parameter #1 [ <optional> $now ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any information on how it actually works behind the scenes? I know it's not super fast, which is understandable. But is it because it parses the code all the time or does it use something smarter, like maybe when the class is loaded into memory it gets digested into smaller chunks and this information is used to "reflect" the actual class?

Comment: @IanBytchek you can check the sourcecode at http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/ext/reflection/

Comment: I can and I did, my C skills are just a little higher than monkey's and I was wondering if you have an answer already. It would be interesting to know without doing the hard work – not the usual approach, promise :)

Comment: @IanBytchek actually, a monkey would beat me at C, so I am afraid I don't have a answer. But you can join the PHP room where lots of knowledgeable people are around who might be able to answer your question.