# What Are the Reflection Classes in php?

Tags: php, class, reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: The Reflection API - Great Addition To PHP With Little Use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377464/php-the-reflection-api-great-addition-to-php-with-little-use)

Finding documentation is one problem, but the quality of documentation is another, equally important, problem. Most developers know the value of accurately commented code, but when i am in the middle of coding, the meaning of your code always seems crystal clear, so comments appear superfluous. Besides, there’s always the ultimate excuse for the absence of internal documentation—i want to keep file size small to reduce download time.

This is often the situation with internal documentation, but external documentation fares no better. It doesn’t make sense to write it as i go because things always change, but, by the time i’ve finished coding, documentation is the furthest thing from my mind.

However: I searched in google and I found a solution called **Reflection Classes** Could any one describe it briefly plz ?

Comment: “i want to keep file size small to reduce download time.” that only applies to files which are downloaded by users. Which is only JS, not PHP or other server-side code. And if you worry about JS file sizes, you should probably use minification instead.

Comment: user, the most part of your question is sharing some thoughts about documentation. And only the last sentence is your question? Would you mind to edit your question that it's more on topic?

Comment: @hakre:I wanna know about Reflection Classes

Comment: @user848689: I edited your question accordingly. Please review if that's okay.

Comment: I don't think this should have been edited.  The extra text is maybe 30 seconds worth of reading but provides insight on exactly what he's wanting the Reflection Classes for.  It also provides insight into the fact that it appears his problem isn't gathering documentation but instead writing it.

Comment: @Charles Sprayberry: I've added it again. Right. No feedback so far from the original author as well.

Comment: @hakre:heheheh!you are so funny man!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Excerpt from the book **Object-oriented PHP: concepts, techniques, and code**
 By *Peter Lavin*](http://books.google.com/books?id=7IVIiQLvBW8C&pg=PA126&lpg=PA126&dq=%22This%20group%20of%20classes%20was%20created%20for%20the%20express%20purpose%20of%20introspecting%20other%20classes.%20These%20classes%20make%20it%20possible%20to%20examine%20the%20properties%20of%20other%20classes%20by%20retrieving%20metadata%20about%20classes;%20you%20can%20even%20use%20them%20to%20examine%20the%20reflection%20classes%20themselves.%22&source=bl&ots=QibbvS4esr&sig=ECjQY-KDnn2Yp-xGykwIVVOqDr4&hl=en&ei=ev4iTsTwLMqSswagwdS5Ag&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBQQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22This%20group%20of%20classes%20was%20created%20for%20the%20express%20purpose%20of%20introspecting%20other%20classes.%20These%20classes%20make%20it%20possible%20to%20examine%20the%20properties%20of%20other%20classes%20by%20retrieving%20metadata%20about%20classes;%20you%20can%20even%20use%20them%20to%20examine%20the%20reflection%20classes%20themselves.%22&f=false):

This group of classes was created for the express purpose of introspecting other classes. These classes
make it possible to examine the properties of other classes by retrieving metadata
about classes; you can even use them to examine the reflection classes themselves.

Reflection provides information about the modifiers of a class or interface—whether that class is final or static, for example.

It can also reveal all the methods and data members of a class and all the modifiers applied to them.

Parameters passed to methods can also be introspected and the names of variables exposed. Through reflection it is possible to automate the documentation of built-in classes or user-defined 
classes.

It turns out that the central repository of information about classes was right in front of us all the time. PHP can tell us all about itself through the mirror of the reflection classes.

The reflection group of classes or Application Programming Interface (API) is made up of a number of different classes and one

interface, shown here:

```
class Reflection
interface Reflector
class ReflectionException extends Exception
class ReflectionFunction implements Reflector
class ReflectionParameter implements Reflector
class ReflectionMethod extends ReflectionFunction
class ReflectionClass implements Reflector
class ReflectionObject extends ReflectionClass
class ReflectionProperty implements Reflector
class ReflectionExtension implements Reflector
```

Look at this list, there is actually no class ancestor common to all reflection classes. On the other hand, the Reflector interface is shared by all classes except Reflection and ReflectionException. 
`ReflectionMethod extendsReflectionFunction, ReflectionObject` extends `ReflectionClass`, and `ReflectionException` extends Exception.

`ReflectionObject` shares all the methods of ReflectionClass; the only difference between these classes is that ReflectionObject takes a class instance rather than a class name as a parameter—using an instance, you can introspect a class without knowing anything about it, even its name.

Comment: Always reference your source. http://goo.gl/zUs5B

Comment: @hakre : i didn't search it in internet!i read this book before and i translate it to my language (persian)!;)

Answer (score 2):

Reflection usually refers to accessing the definition of types and functions during runtime. It is most useful in static languages such as C# or Java, but I guess it could be useful in dynamic languages such as PHP too.

In PHP, it seems it can be used to *retrieve* documentation of existing classes/functions. But I don't think it will help you with writing documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Reflection explained in general is done on the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29):

> In computer science, reflection is the process by which a computer program can observe (do type introspection) and modify its own structure and behavior at runtime.

(Excerpt)

The concrete implementation in PHP is documented in the book [Reflection (Introduction) <sup>**PHP Manual**</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.reflection.php):

> PHP 5 comes with a complete reflection API that adds the ability to reverse-engineer classes, interfaces, functions, methods and extensions. Additionally, the reflection API offers ways to retrieve doc comments for functions, classes and methods.

(Excerpt)

Answer (score 1):

The reflection class is used to get information about the current state of the application. It's called reflection, because it looks at it's self, and can tell you information about the program your running, at run time.